# How do I prevent jquery address from triggering a change?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-address

I'm using [jquery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) to track changes with the browsers nav buttons and have hit a bump in the road.  The plugin works great for simple html links but I have a dropdown menu that is triggering an address change when the parent node is clicked.  The drop down menu looks like this:

```
    <li id="messages"><a href="#" class="drop" >Messages</a>
       <div class="drop2columns dropcontent">
            <div class="col_2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="msgs_received" href="#msgs_received">Inbox</a></li>
                    <li><a id="msgs_sent" href="msgs_sent">Sent</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

When I click the "Messages" portion to trigger my dropdown the location is getting set to "/" (I would assume because my href="#")

Is there a way to ignore this onclick event?

I've been thinking about creating an onClick event that gets/sets the same URL so it doesn't trigger jqueries address change method.  This seems more like a hack then a solution though.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS, try this:

```
$("#messages").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Looks like it's preventing anything from happening:         $('#messages').click(function(e) {
     $(this).children(menuItemChildren).slideDown(0);
     $(this).hover(function() {
     }, function(){ 
  $(this).children(menuItemChildren).slideUp(0);
     });
     e.preventDefault();
 });